# Smatch -- The Source Matcher

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, patch

I Just jumped into the Linux kernel Code and my goal is to submit some trivial patches.I want to use Smatch [ http://smatch.sourceforge.net/ ] but I'm not getting how to use it. Can any one write a tutorial or point me to one.